# Trace32: How to Focus view on a user provided pc(program counter)

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I got a situation on ARM controller, where in the underlying OS layer, an exception is reported by calling osException(). The caller of this function also passes the pc(program counter). I have set a breakpoint on osException() and can print the value of pc on trace32 AREA. Further, I would like to focus the Trace32 view to the source code where this program counter is pointing to. How can I do it using a trace32 scripts ?

Comment: How do you currently print the PC to the AREA window? Do you have the PC saved in a PRACTICE macro, or do you get it with some TRACE32 function?

Comment: its is a parameter passed when calling osException(uint pc). When the breakpoint is hit at this function call, the value of the variable pc is printed using Var.PRINT "Exception at  
 " pc

Answer (score 2):

I think the command you are searching for is

```
List Var.VALUE(pc)
```

The command `List [<address>]` opens a windows showing the target application a the given address. If you omit the parameter , the window will focus on the address, where the *current* program counter is pointing to. (The *current* program counter point of course somewhere inside osException())

The function `Var.VALUE(<HllExpr>)` returns the value of the given high-level-language expression. So if you have a variable `pc` it return the value of this variable for all TRACE32 commands not starting with `Var.`

Comment: if i want to redirect the program counter values output in the window to a log file, how can i?

Comment: List Var.VALUE(pc) -> "Symbol Not Found" error is seen for Var

Comment: The original questioner wrote that pc "is a parameter passed when calling osException(uint pc)." So `pc` was a variable and not the current program counter.
In your case @AlphaGoku, there seems to be no variable called `pc`. 
To open a List window for the current program counter, just execute the command `List` without any following value.

Comment: The question about logging the program counter is a total different question. Please open a new thread for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597493/logging-pc-values-to-a-file-in-trace32