# Logging PC values to a file in Trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

How can I log the Program counter values to a file in Trace 32 continuously.
The use case is something like, trace through the PC values like in a waveform, to know the exact instructions that were executed just before a crash occurred.

Comment: Does your processor support on-chip or off-chip trace?

Comment: how can i check that ?

Comment: Either check the processor reference manual / data sheet, or ask the processor manufacturer.

Comment: it supports both

Comment: i see the arm cortex r8 controller i am using has DBGPCSR that holds the PC values. How can i log this value to a file continuously?